# Getting Data values from database to save to session storage?

Tags: php, sql, database, session, storage

i want to make so my webpage takes values from a table in a database and displays them on the screen in the format that is shown below in the code, however i would then like to take the values for BikeID and ContactEmail and save them to session storage to be used on the update confirm page which your taken to when the update button is clicked. however the first issue is that the values wont save to the session storage and the second is that even if they did would the session get the correct value according to the Table/BikeID selected where the button is clicked. Image of the page layout after the code is run is below.

if anyone has any ideas i would be grateful.

```
  <?php

        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

        $username="Username"; // change this to your database username
        $password="Password"; // change this to your database password
        $database="Database"; // change this to your database username

        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblBikeStolen, tblBike WHERE tblBike.BikeID=tblBikeStolen.BikeID";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<div id='UpdateTable'><table><tr><td> User No: " . $row["User"] . "</td> 
 <td>Bike ID: " . $row["BikeID"]. "</td><td> Contact: " . $row["ContactEmail"] . "</td></tr><tr><td> 
 Reported Time: " . $row["ReportTime"] . "</td><td> Address: " . $row["Address"] . "</td><td> Bike 
 MPN: " . $row["BikeMPN"] . "</td></tr><tr><td> Bike Brand: " . $row["BikeBrand"] . "</td><td> Bike 
 Model: " . $row["BikeModel"] . "</td><td> Bike Type: " . $row["BikeType"] . "</td><tr><td> 
 Investigation Notes: " . $row["UpdateNotes"] . "</td></tr><tr><td> Status: " . $row["Status"] . " 
 </td></tr><tr><form><button class='btn btn-primary btnUpdateInvest' type='submit' 
 value='Update'formaction='ConfirmUpdate.php' onClick='UpdateFunctionDAO.php'>Update</button></form> 
 </tr></table></div>";
                $BikeID = $row['BikeID'];
                $_SESSION["BikeID"] = $BikeID;
                $ContactEmail = $row['ContactEmail'];
                $_SESSION["ContactEmail"] = $ContactEmail;
                }
                } else { echo "0 results"; }

                $conn->close();

    ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend starting simple and then expanding your use case:

Instead of using `formaction = 'ConfirmUpdate.php'`, try using `formaction = 'ConfirmUpdate.php?bikeid=<your-bike-id>&contactemail=<the-contact-email>'`

In ConfirmUpdate.php, check if `$_GET['bikeid']` and `$_GET['contactemail']` are set and valid. If you didn't get either of those keys or if they were invalid, write a meaningful error message on the screening instructing the user what to do next.

If you received both those keys and their values were reasonable, you can store them in a session for future processing. Once your processing is done, clear out that information from the session.

Your PHP code will look something like this:

```
echo "...value='Update' formaction='ConfirmUpdate.php?bikeid=" . $row["BikeID"] . "&amp;contactemail=" . $row["ContactEmail"] . "' onClick='UpdateFunctionDAO.php'>...";
```

Try this and see how it works. You might have to do more work after this to ensure that the data you are publishing on the page is sanitized and not susceptible to injection.

## Example

Let's say your initial page is called `test.php` and it looks like this:

```
<?php

    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    $username=""; // change this to your database username
    $password=""; // change this to your database password
    $database=""; // change this to your database username

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "your sql query";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $displayText = sprintf('<div>Some other info. Bike ID is %s and contact is %s.</div>',
                $row['bikeid'],
                $row['contactemail']
            );

            $form = sprintf('
                <form method="post" action="ConfirmUpdate.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="bikeid" value="%s">
                    <input type="hidden" name="contactemail" value="%s">
                    %s
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>',
                $row['bikeid'],
                $row['contactemail'],
                $displayText
            );

            echo $form;
        }
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Result

[image]

Your `ConfirmUpdate.php` will look like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['bikeid'] = $_POST['bikeid'];
    $_SESSION['contactemail'] = $_POST['contactemail'];

    echo sprintf('Received bike id %s and contact email %s',
        $_SESSION['bikeid'],
        $_SESSION['contactemail']
    );
?>
```

When you click on the first button, you will be taken to ConfirmUpdate page, which will look like this:

```
Received bike id 1 and contact email test@gmail.com
```

When you click the 2nd button, you will see:

```
Received bike id 2 and contact email test@yahoo.com
```

Test this out on your own systems and you should be able to replicate this code in your project.

Comment: Ok thank you ill have a go to see if this fix works, ill let you know

Comment: Don't worry about the session first. Just try to ensure that each update button has a formaction like the one I have show. Once you get to that step, we can discuss the next step. Were you able to ensure that update button had the formaction like I mentioned?

Comment: Yes each update button has the formaction as described.

Comment: this is the code i have so far . `
                $BikeID = $_GET['BikeID']; 
                $ContactEmail = $_GET['ContactEmail']; 
                
                $_SESSION["BikeID"] = "$BikeID";
                $_SESSION["ContactEmail"] = "$ContactEmail";

                echo "<table><tr><td id='BikeID'>Bike ID: " . $_SESSION["BikeID"] . "</td><td id='ContactEmail'> Contact: " . $_SESSION["ContactEmail"] . "</td></tr></table>";`

Comment: Awesome. In ConfirmUpdate.php, right after `<?php`, type `var_dump($_GET)`. When you try your application again and reach ConfirmUpdate, you will see the bike ID and contact email. Do you see that?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing. First, instead of using this: `...Bike ID: " . $_SESSION["BikeID"] . "</td><td id='ContactEmail'> Contact: " . $_SESSION["ContactEmail"] . "</td>...`, use this: `...Bike ID: " . $_GET["BikeID"] . "</td><td id='ContactEmail'> Contact: " . $_GET["ContactEmail"] . "</td>...`. Do you see correct information on the screen?

Comment: No i am getting "array(0) { }"

Comment: Okay, what is your URL looking like?

Comment: it says this at the end "/UpdateInvestigationStatus/ConfirmUpdate.php?"

Comment: There's nothing after the question mark? I was expecting `/UpdateInvestigationStatus/ConfirmUpdate.php?bikeid=1&contactemail=name@domain.com`

Comment: Alright, go to the previous page. Right click the button and inspect it's HTML. What do you see in its html? You can copy and paste it here.

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-primary btnUpdateInvest" type="submit" value="Update" formaction="ConfirmUpdate.php?bikeid=1&amp;contactemail=Alexsimmonds@gmail.com" onclick="UpdateFunctionDAO.php">Update</button>` it appears to be all be here

Comment: Okay, gotcha. I think we are getting close. Can you confirm what your `<form ...` tag looks like? You can remove any confidential information from that tag and paste it here.

Comment: `<form>
                <?php
                $_GET['BikeID']; 
                $_GET['ContactEmail']; 
                
                $_SESSION["BikeID"] = $_GET['BikeID'];
                $_SESSION["ContactEmail"] = $_GET['ContactEmail'];

                echo "<table><tr><td id='BikeID'>Bike ID: " . $_SESSION["BikeID"] . "</td><td id='ContactEmail'> Contact: " . $_SESSION["ContactEmail"] . "</td></tr></table>";
                ?>
                <br>`

Comment: `<textarea type="text" placeholder="Enter Investigation Notes" class="form-control" id="UpdateNotes"></textarea><br>
                <select id="Status" name="Status">
                    <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
                    <option value="Open">Open</option>
  </select>
                <button onclick="location.replace('../index.php');" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                <input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="postStuff();" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>`

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Let me see if I can whip up an example quick.

Comment: @alexsimmonds I have an example ready for you. Test it out and that should answers you are looking for.

Comment: **Thank you, Thank you, Thank you** Really appreciate your time on this the example you gave worked great i had to add some css to the buttons styling as it was offset from the correct item so i moved it `margin-top:-50px:` which then fixed the issue but apart from that everything worked great. Again thank you for your time. you've been a great help. :)

Comment: Awesome! You can put closure to your question by marking this answer as accepted so that other users can find it as a solved problem.